# Put new objects into Dask queue

Tags: python, queue, dask, dask-distributed

I want to use Dask distributed queues to share some data with other clients.
The data I want to share is an object of a class data :
where the index is a list, the data is either a future of a dask collection and the name is a string.

```
class data:
    index = list()
    data = None

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

I used register_generic to register this new object to be serialized like here:

```
from distributed.protocol import register_generic 
register_generic(metadata)
ds = data(name)
ds.data = darray 
ds.index = index
q = Queue("data").put(ds)
```

However I got this error :

> TypeError: can not serialize 'data' object

Is there other available ways to allow putting new objects to queues?
Else what do you suggest to use instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docstring for Queue:

> ```
> Elements of the Queue must be either Futures or msgpack-encodable data
> (ints, strings, lists, dicts).  All data is sent through the scheduler so
> it is wise not to send large objects.  To share large objects scatter the
> data and share the future instead.
> ```

Without making an extension for msgpack to encode your class, or sending an alternate representation (e.g., JSON), you should wrap your value in a Dask future, like this

```
f = client.scatter(ds)
q.put(ds)
```

When you get the value, you will need to unwrap it

```
value = client.gather(q.get())
```

Note that queues are a niche and not much use part of distributed.

Comment: I was wondering to know why is there these restrictions for queue (in termes of data to put and get) comparing to pubsub and publish_dataset ?

Comment: pubsub and variables are much more recent, that might be all